# Howto display an SQL SUM query result (variable 1) with MIN, MAX and AVG values (variable 2) using PHP?

Tags: mysql, sum, max, average, min

I have read the recommended answers none of which pertain to my subject.

A database about surgeries performed contains lots of tables and these lots of fields: table `dat_patient` (patients, abbreviated "p") numbers about 100, and table `dat_optherapie` (surgeries, abbreviated "op") about 1,000 fields. Here is a description of the fields I use for my query:

`p.ID` is the autoincremental patient index which is correlated to `op.patID` in the surgery table.

`op.OP1OPVerfahren` contains the surgical procedure each of which can have 29 string values (from "1" to "28" and "99").

`op.OP1Datum` contains the date of surgery.

`op.revision` shows how many revisions of a given data set there are (important for tracking changes).

I now want to enumerate all different surgical procedures (29) performed in a table. Embedding the SQL query code into my PHP frame works fine:

**Basic SQL query**:

```
    SELECT
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "4") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass banded",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "5") AS "Scopinaro",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "6") AS "Duodenal Switch (DS)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "7") AS "Sleeve Resection",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "8") AS "Gastric Pacemaker",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "9") AS "Billroth II",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "10") AS "Gastroplasty",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "11") AS "Fobi / Capella Bypass",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "12") AS "Larrad",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "13") AS "Santoro",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "14") AS "DJB",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "15") AS "TOGA",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "16") AS "Endobarrier",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "17") AS "Gastric Plication",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "18") AS "Stomaphyx",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "19") AS "Omega Loop Bypass",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "20") AS "Omega Loop Bypass banded",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "21") AS "Long Limb Bypass",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "22") AS "Distal Very Long Gastric Bypass (Thurnheer)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "23") AS "Endoscopic Sclerosation",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "24") AS "Swedish Adjustable Gastric Bypass (SAGB)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "25") AS "Vertical Banded Gastroplasty (VBG)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "26") AS "Plastic Abdominal Wall Reconstruction (PAWR)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "27") AS "Inner Hernia Repair",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "28") AS "Single Anastomosis Duodeno-Ileal Bypass with Sleeve Gastrectomy (SADI-S)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "99") AS "Anderes OP-Verfahren",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"

        FROM dat_patient p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID

        WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dat_optherapie op2 WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision);
```

The **result in an SQL editor** looks like follows (the green arrow only sums up all surgeries found):

[image: SQL query result in SQL editor]

The **result in my PHP code** looks like follows:

[image: PHP display of the SQL query result]

I now introduce the duration for each surgery performed:

`op.OP1Dauer` which is the number of minutes it took to perform the surgery

I want to extend the SQL query code by the minimum, maximum and average duration over all summed-up surgeries as three additional columns:

```
    [...]
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe",

    MIN(op.OP1Dauer) AS "MIN",
    MAX(op.OP1Dauer) AS "MAX",
    AVG(op.OP1Dauer) AS "AVG"

    FROM dat_patient p
    [...]
```

PHP should display this as follows:

```
+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Surgeries performed     | Sum     | MIN     | MAX     | AVG     |
+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| surgery x               | 9       | 25      | 348     | 125     |
+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| surgery y               | 107     | 87      | 244     | 167     |
+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| surgery z               | 97      | 5       | 57      | 23      |
+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| sum                     | 1019    | not really relevant here    |
+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

When I change the SQL query in the following mode ...

**Changed SQL query**:

```
    SELECT
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",

        [... abreviated because the same as in first SQL query ...]

        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "27") AS "Inner Hernia Repair",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "28") AS "Single Anastomosis Duodeno-Ileal Bypass with Sleeve Gastrectomy (SADI-S)",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "99") AS "Anderes OP-Verfahren",
        SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe",

        MIN(op.OP1Dauer),
        MAX(op.OP1Dauer),
        AVG(op.OP1Dauer)
                    
        FROM dat_optherapie op
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dat_patient p ON op.patID = p.ID
        WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"

        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dat_optherapie op2 WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)

        GROUP BY op.OP1OPVerfahren
```

..., I see the following **result in the SQL editor**:

[image: Yes, I know: -1! This is my test database in which I allow such values.]

Basically, this is what displays the (controlled) correct values (please do not blame me for the "-1", these are my experimental data, and the "-1" has been left over for testing purposes ...). Furthermore, I have changed the primary table `dat_patient` joined by `dat_optherapie` to the other way round (even if not displayed here in the query, I need the association to the patient table due to an internal differentiation of which patients are real and which are for testing purposes only).

Within the PHP code, I display results in the following way:

```
    <?php

    [... Preceding PHP code for exporting the results as CSV / XLSX ...]

    function getOP1OPVerfahrenStratification() {
        global $oDatabase;

        $qQuery = ' [... SQL query ...] ';

        $rQuery = mysql_query($qQuery, $oDatabase);
        $result = array("count" => mysql_num_rows($rQuery ), "result" => $rQuery);
        return $result;
    }

    function writeOP1OPVerfahrenStratification($rQuery) {
        if (!$rQuery) {
            $message = '<br>';
            $message .= '<b>Ungültige Abfrage:</b> ' . mysql_error() . '<br>';
            $message .= '<b>Gesamte Abfrage:</b> ' . $qQuery . '<br>';
            echo $message;
        }

        if (mysql_num_rows($rQuery) == 0) {
            $message = '<br>';
            $message .= '<p class="error">Zu diesem Zeitraum liegen noch keine Daten vor.</p> ' . mysql_error() . '<br>';
            echo $message;
        }

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rQuery)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo "Keine Operation durchgef&uuml;hrt";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['Keine Operation durchgeführt'];
            echo '</td>';

            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "MIN";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['MIN'];
            echo '</td>';
            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "MAX";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['MAX'];
            echo '</td>';
            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "AVG";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['AVG'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)'];
            echo '</td>';

            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "MIN";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['MIN'];
            echo '</td>';
            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "MAX";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['MAX'];
            echo '</td>';
            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "AVG";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['AVG'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

            echo '</tr>';

            [...]

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo "Single Anastomosis Duodeno-Ileal Bypass with Sleeve Gastrectomy (SADI-S)";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['Single Anastomosis Duodeno-Ileal Bypass with Sleeve Gastrectomy (SADI-S)'];
            echo '</td>';

            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "MIN";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['MIN'];
            echo '</td>';
            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "MAX";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['MAX'];
            echo '</td>';
            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "AVG";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['AVG'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo "Anderes OP-Verfahren";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['Anderes OP-Verfahren'];
            echo '</td>';

            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "MIN";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['MIN'];
            echo '</td>';
            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "MAX";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['MAX'];
            echo '</td>';
            //echo '<td>';
            //echo "AVG";
            //echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="data_table_r">';
            echo $row['AVG'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style="font-size: 30px;">';
            echo "Summe";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td  class="data_table_r" style="font-size: 30px;">';
            echo $row['Summe'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }

    $beginn = microtime(true);
    $ListResult = getOP1OPVerfahrenStratification();
    $dauer = microtime(true) - $beginn;
    $ListCount = $ListResult['count'];
    ?>

    [... HTML, CSS, JavaScript files - begin ...]

    <?php
        writeOP1OPVerfahrenStratification($ListResult['result']);
        mysql_free_result($result);
    ?>

    [... HTML, CSS, JavaScript files - end ...]
```

You may find all that built in a circumstantial way, I partially agree - nevertheless, my question is not about beautification.

**Along that way or already in my SQL query I flaw up the code for a proper display in PHP.** I see that I get displayed only one and the always same single value triple of MIN, Max and AVG:

[image: PHP result display]

I would very much appreciate if someone could show me where my error is. The PHP table display takes place in the lots of `echo ...` commands, and I guess I should integrate the the MIN, MAX and AVG commands there in the proper way which I have not understood to do so far.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: I know this, but this contributes NULL solution to my question. The server I am forced to use permits only PHP 5 for reasons I am unable to influence. Under PHP 7, the same problem results. Thank you very much for -2 points, but I do not care.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. And please refrain from posting pictures of text, and moaning.

Comment: I think you might have wrong expectations about this site. Please visit [tour]. People will downvote the post if they don't find it useful. I guess your problem is not popular enough. You can try to edit it to make it more interesting. It's difficult to say which question will be good enough to catch the attention of the community. Don't take downvotes personally and remember this is not a personal help forum.

Comment: Look. We talk about formalisms. Not a single advice to my problem. Maybe you have seen that I am a physician. A surgeon, to be precise. If you had pain in your lower right quadrant indicating a possible appendicitis, would you then by accidentally getting me as your treating physician like to be rebuffed because you opened the door wrongly or discuss financial specialities before I even think of performing surgery on you? No, you would not. You would expect - with any right to do so - HELP from me. And this is the same I do expect here. But maybe I do not get it and it's all about formalisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OWN SOLUTION:

Of course, the above-mentioned agglomeration of one `SUM(...)` after another does not work as this builds up an array of SQL query result sets in rows which do display the associated MIN, MAX and AVG duration for the type (not the sum!) of surgery performed but cannot be displayed without further ado using PHP.

The resulting SQL query code is like this:

```
    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 0 THEN "keines"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 1 THEN "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 2 THEN "Gastric Banding"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 3 THEN "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 4 THEN "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass banded"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 5 THEN "Scopinaro"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 6 THEN "Duodenal Switch (DS)"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 7 THEN "Sleeve Resection"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 8 THEN "Gastric Pacemaker"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 9 THEN "Billroth II"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 10 THEN "Gastroplasty"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 11 THEN "Fobi / Capella Bypass"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 12 THEN "Larrad"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 13 THEN "Santoro"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 14 THEN "DJB"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 15 THEN "TOGA"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 16 THEN "Endobarrier"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 17 THEN "Gastric Plication"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 18 THEN "Stomaphyx"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 19 THEN "Omega Loop Bypass"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 20 THEN "Omega Loop Bypass banded"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 21 THEN "Long Limb Bypass"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 22 THEN "Distal Very Long Gastric Bypass (Thurnheer)"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 23 THEN "Endoscopic Sclerosation"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 24 THEN "Swedish Adjustable Gastric Bypass (SAGB)"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 25 THEN "Vertical Banded Gastroplasty (VBG)"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 26 THEN "Plastic Abdominal Wall Reconstruction (PAWR)"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 27 THEN "Inner Hernia Repair"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 28 THEN "Single Anastomosis Duodeno-Ileal Bypass with Sleeve Gastrectomy (SADI-S)"
        WHEN op.OP1OPVerfahren = 99 THEN "Anderes OP-Verfahren"
    END "OP-Verfahren",

    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe der Eingriffe",

    MIN(op.OP1Dauer) AS "MIN",
    MAX(op.OP1Dauer) AS "MAX",
    ROUND(AVG(op.OP1Dauer),2) AS "AVG"
                    
    FROM dat_patient p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID
    WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "1950-01-01" AND "2050-12-31"
    AND op.OP1Dauer != -1
    AND p.Testzwecke = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dat_optherapie op2 WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision)

    GROUP BY op.OP1OPVerfahren
    ORDER BY op.OP1OPVerfahren
```

This leads to the following PHP table display:

[image: Final PHP table display as it should be]

The last three colums are MIN, MAX and AVG not yet named (an adaptation in the respective style sheet is still necessary). Additionally, doing things this way, automatically those operative procedures are not displayed which have no calculable min, max and avg duration as there, obviously, cannot be any when 0 surgeries have been performed.

Comment: Addendum: Since this is the native SQL query code, it can be used for my initially mentioned PHP 5 as well as any PHP 7 code. The only difference now is that the generation of this table implies the use of `foreach ($row as $field => $value)` within the initially mentioned `while ...` statement.